# how to classifying that is a single digit or multiple digit

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, image-segmentation, digit

I have an image that contain digits.

[image: original image]

there are: 1, 153, 25, 50, 23, and 40

For every single digit, I have no problem with digit recognition. I can recognize there are 1, 1, 5, 3, 5, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 0.

Now, I want to made them become 1, 153, 25, 50, 23, and 40.

My approach is, make the image become high blur, so the boundingbox of the digits is meet with the other digit's boundingbox. then extract the digit inside the huge boundingbox of multiple bounding box.

my expectation is like this

[image: expectation]

but, the reality is like this

[image: reality]

1, 153, 25, 5, 0, and 2340

because,

- the distance of 5 and 0 is too far
- the distance 23 and 40 is too close

My question is, is there another approach for classifying those are single or multiple digit? If yes, how? :)
Thank you very much :)

*sorry for my bad english

**I using opencv c++

Comment: For the case of 50, you can fix a distance between digits, say d. If digits have distance greater than d, then they are different numbers. For the case of 2340, I do not think that is 23 and 40. I believe that is 2340.

Comment: Yes, fix distance can be implemented in printed character. But in handwritten character that written in white paper (no lines), I think that it quite difficult, because of 'too free'. I mean, for handwritten, there is no fix distance like printed text. Sometimes, human is just writing without care the distance of digit. That's why I made those example, 50 and 2340, I want to solve those cases, 'too far' and 'too close'.
This image is just an example. Please, correct me if I wrong. :)

Comment: It seems a 2340 for me too...

Comment: Can you first detect all the digit, then use a distance that is proportional to the size of each digit?

Comment: @lulu Were you able to get the quick solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

The computation time of blurring then finding bounding boxes is large compared to this:

If you can pick out each of those digits then you must at least have a center point for each digit. I would further this by finding the width and height of each number along with the rotation. With this information I would apply a set of rules that correspond to how one would read the number.

These rules could work:

1. Start with an empty graph of node number equal to the number of digits
2. Does the digit under test have any other digit less than one width away (or two widths from each other's center point)?
3. If so then does both digits have the same rotation (+/- tolerance)
4. If so then is the rotation 90 (+/- tol) degrees to the line between the center points of the two digits?
5. Determine order using the vector difference of the two points
6. Create a directional edge between the two digits
7. Check for another digit on the opposite side (Shortcut)
8. Repeat for the next digit
9. Walk along the graph to find your set of numbers

Considering problems like this I would prefer to use probabilities to order a set of possible solutions, so then your program could ask an operator or if it gets stuck assuming one thing it can go back and choose the next "best" one.

Hope this helps, I envy your digit recognition skills :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not blur the image. Just extract the individual characters and their bounding boxes. You could then iteratively apply a euclidean distance threshold for their centroids to merge the bounding boxes together, one at a time. You could then model each number as a linked list and keep adding to the list on either side of an element by simple direction heuristics.